# Reorder of GridView is not working in windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, reorderlist

I need to provide user with reordering of listview items facility.And I followed http://w3facility.org/question/xamlc-what-event-fires-after-reordering-a-gridview/

But this doesn't update after draged and droped at others place(View remains same).Someone help me in achieving my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried that before updating my visual studio to full release.After
>   updating to latest full version of Visual studio 2015 its working
>   peacefully with out altering the code.We need to use ObservableCollection and set CanDrag,AllowDrop to true.